# How to index crawled "html" from Apache Nutch to Solr?

Tags: html, indexing, solr, nutch

I want to index the source code of my crawled web pages by Apache Nutch (v1.17) to index in Solr (8.6.3), but don't know how to do that? At least I just get a prepared version indexed to Solr **content** (see below).

```
{
  "tstamp":"2020-11-19T08:41:15.908Z",
  "digest":"fdc7532e799d4a3a434be4be67c36bb3b",
  "boost":1.0,
  .
  .
  .
  "content":"Algorithm Engineering Group ....",
 "_version_":16837969286885539843
}
```

I have already looked at the **index-writers.xml**, but I still don't know how to do that. Maybe you know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Nutch index tool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=122916842) provides a command-line option to index the raw content of web pages:

```sh
$> bin/nutch index
...
-addBinaryContent  index raw/binary content in field `binaryContent`
-base64            use Base64 encoding for binary content
...
```

Note: be aware of PDF and other binary formats the crawler may visit!